# Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::header()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-passport

Hi i was using a cors middleware which seems to work fine until i added Laravel Passport now there is a problem with it.. it shows the error

```
 Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::header() on line number 36
```

This is my middleware :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;

class Cors
{

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

// ALLOW OPTIONS METHOD
        $headers = [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Authorization , Access-Control-Request-Headers"
        ];


        if ($request->getMethod() == "OPTIONS") {
// The client-side application can set only headers allowed in Access-Control-Allow-Headers
            return Response::make('OK', 200, $headers);
        }

        $response = $next($request);
        foreach ($headers as $key => $value)
            $response->header($key, $value);
        return $response;
    }

}
```

the issue is after the if condition .. Any help will be appreaciated thanks

Comment: Can you share your `composer.json` file so we can see the versions of each librairies ?

Comment: please try this: `$response->headers->set($key, $value)`

Comment: I was under the impression that passport handled CORS for you?

Answer (score 55):

Hi I faced the same problem. It seems like it was an error in Passport and there are many developers are in the same situation. I just found the solution to this issue. The reason why we get this error is because Response object we get in `middleware` is usually an instance of `Illuminate\Http\Response` class which we can set Response headers using the method `header('Header-Key', 'Header-Value')` whereas the Request handled by Passport will be an instance of `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response` that's why we got the error `Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::header()`

Below is the code that I use to tackle this error and now everything works fine. I hope it helps other developers get the idea how to fix it and then adapt to their code.

```
$response = $next($request);
$IlluminateResponse = 'Illuminate\Http\Response';
$SymfonyResopnse = 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response';
$headers = [
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Authorization , Access-Control-Request-Headers',
];

if($response instanceof $IlluminateResponse) {
    foreach ($headers as $key => $value) {
        $response->header($key, $value);
    }
    return $response;
}

if($response instanceof $SymfonyResopnse) {
    foreach ($headers as $key => $value) {
        $response->headers->set($key, $value);
    }
    return $response;
}

return $response;
```

And in my `Kernel.php`

```
protected $middleware = [
    \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
    // ....
];
```

Comment: Awesome dude! Saved my life :)

Comment: The Illuminate response extends from the Symfony response so you can just always treat the response as if it were the Symfony response rather than handling them separately.

Comment: when api throttle limit is exceeded in laravel, 429 error is also returned as 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response' so this prevents the error in this case. Thanks.

Comment: Disappointing to see this is still an issue almost 5 years later.

Answer (score 9):

It seems that from your application you are getting the `HttpFoundation\Response`, which doesn't have the `header` method. So instead you can try to set the header to the `headers` variable of the `HttpFoundation\Response`.

```
foreach ($headers as $key => $value)
    $response->headers->set($key, $value);
return $response;
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem when I did this

```
return Response::stream($callback, 200, $headers);
```

I solve it by simply putting forward slash ( \ ) before Response like this:

```
return \Response::stream($callback, 200, $headers);
```

Try this solution: Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 response objects:

- Laravel: Illuminate\Http\Response
- Symfony: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response

Passport returns Symfony's response object.

Laravel's response object is extending Symfony's and adds some convenient methods such as `header()`, however that method is not defined on Symfony's response object.

You can simply always use Symfony's underlying method (that laravel extends):

```php
$response->headers->set($key, $value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by placing the project in desktop .  So if your project is inside a folder in desktop or some other place just place remove it from there and place it in desktop.