# Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::withCookie()

Tags: php, laravel

**Laravel**: 6.18.1
PHP: 7.4

Middleware in laravel is creating this error

```
{
    "message": "Call to undefined method Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Response::withCookie()",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError",
```

Code which is giving me error

```
if (!$request->hasCookie('ppl') || ($request->hasCookie('ppl') && $ppl_cookie->ppl_id != $ppl->ppl_id)) {
            if (Auth::check()) {
                Event::dispatch('ppl.updated', [Auth::user(), $ppl]);
            }
            return $next($request)->withCookie(cookie()->forever('ppl', $ppl));
        }
```

I don't understand issue. cookie is not stored in browser

**Edit**

Middleware class

```
<?php 
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use App\System\Models\People;
use App;
use Event;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
use Session;

class VerifyPeople
{

    protected $app;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->app = app();
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
       $People_cookie = json_decode($request->cookie('People'));
        if (!empty($request->route()) && in_array($request->route()->uri(), $this->excepts)) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        if ($request->getHost()) {
            $domain_url = cleanUrl($request->getHost());
            $People = People::where('People_url', '=', $domain_url)->remember(LONG_TERM_CACHE_TIMEOUT)->cacheTags(TAG_LONGTERM_DATA)->first();
        } elseif ($request->hasCookie('People')) {
            $People = $People_cookie;
        }

        if (empty($People)) {
            $People = People::where("People_id", People::DEFAULT_People)->remember(LONG_TERM_CACHE_TIMEOUT)->cacheTags(TAG_LONGTERM_DATA)->first();
        }
        $this->app->singleton('People', function () use ($People) {
            return $People;
        });
        if (!$request->hasCookie('People') || ($request->hasCookie('People') && $People_cookie->People_id != $People->People_id)) {
            if (Auth::check()) {
                Event::dispatch('People.updated', [Auth::user(), $People]);
            }
            return $next($request)->withCookie(cookie()->forever('People', $People));
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the full middleware class ?

Comment: @Ersoy updated!!

Comment: when you `dd($next($request));` it is supposed print an instance of `Illuminate\Http\Response` which can access to `ResponseTrait` and `withCookie` method. in your error it says it is the instance of base class(`Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response`) which is extended by `Illuminate\Http\Response` which doesn't use `ResponseTrait`.

Comment: @Ersoy: not getting you

Comment: @Ersoy: Cookie is not set in browser

Comment: Haven't you've just messed up your parenthesis? `return $next($request->withCookie(cookie()->forever('People', $People)));`instead of `return $next($request)->withCookie(cookie()->forever('People', $People));`

Answer (score 0):

In the middleware when you do `dd($next($request));` it is supposed print an instance of `Illuminate\Http\Response` which can access to `ResponseTrait` and `withCookie` method within the trait..

In your case, the instance of `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response` is giving error which is extended by `Illuminate\Http\Response` but doesn't use `ResponseTrait`. That's the reason `withCookie` method didn't found.

There may be several reasons such as, before this middleware is executed - another middleware is modifying default response with `Symfony` response.

Here is the `withCookie` method.

```
public function withCookie($cookie)
{
    if (is_string($cookie) && function_exists('cookie')) {
        $cookie = call_user_func_array('cookie', func_get_args());
    }

    $this->headers->setCookie($cookie);

    return $this;
}
```

What it does is calling setCookie method of headers. What you may do is;

Replace

```
return $next($request)->withCookie(cookie()->forever('People', $People));
```

with

```
$response = $next($request);
$response->headers->setCookie(cookie()->forever('People', $People));

return $response;
```

While looking; i found a [similar case to yours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44289066/2188922)

Comment: @BhumiShah updated the answer - you may go to `replace` part for solution